# python: __name__ doesn't return variable name after assigning a function to it

Tags: python

I want to assign a function to a variable, and then I want to get its variable name. So for below code, after I assign `my_test_2 = my_test`, I want to get string of "my_test_2", but it returns my_test. Is there a way to return my_test_2?

```
In [2]: def my_test():
   ...:     print 1
   ...:     

In [3]: my_test_2 = my_test

In [4]: my_test_2.__name__
Out[4]: 'my_test'     # I need value of 'my_test_2', how to achieve this?
```

**Update about why I need this feature:**
I want to run several functions simultaneously, then in wait for a timeout period, to get all the result for different function. So I tried to return a map for  parallel_async. And the key is the function name. If I need to call the function multiple times, then the key will be overwritten, so I redefine the function as a different variable name. With this I expected to has different key. Maybe there are better solutions? Currently I just want to get the variable name as the key.

```
def parallel_async(args_list,timeout_second):
    """parallel run many different functions, all should return in timeout window,
    otherwise the return value for that function will be None

e.g:

    def my_wait1(a):
        print a
        time.sleep(a)
        return a

    my_wait2 = my_wait1

    result = parallel_async([[my_wait,1],
                    [my_wait2,2]],2)
    print result

    result should be:
        {'my_wait': None, 'my_wait1': 2}

    """
    result = {}
    print 'aaa'
    def run_func(args):
        func_name = itertoolz.first(args)
        func_args = list(itertoolz.rest(args))
        print func_name
        print func_args
        result.update({func_name.__name__:func_name(*func_args)})

    pool = ThreadPool(len(args_list))
    try:
        pool.map_async(run_func,args_list).get(timeout_second)
    except Exception as e:
        pool.close()
    return result
```

Comment: You could set `my_test_2.__name__ = 'my_test_2'` if you really wanted to. It would be bizarre. Bear in mind that `my_test` and `my_test_2` are the _same thing_, so it's not going to give you a different name depending on what identifier you're using for it.

Comment: It is sometimes done for partial objects, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Comment: Question is where do you need such functionality?